# N-length string loop cut N times: piece length as N $\to \infty$?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose I take a loop of string of length N units, and mark N points on it at independant and uniformly random (not necessarily integral) points along its length.

(So for example suppose I have a 3 inch string:  I might make marks at 0.425 inches, 0.924 inches and 2.4155 inches clockwise from some arbitrary origin point on the loop.)

Then lets say I cut the string loop at each of the N points.  I will be left with N pieces of string.  The average length of these pieces of string will be 1 unit (as their total length is N units, and there are N of them: $N/N = 1$).

As N approaches infinity, what is the distribution of the length of these pieces of string?

I think the answer is a probability density function with center of mass at 1, and total integral 1.

What is this function?  Does it have a name?

Comment: *"I think the answer is a probability density function with center of mass at 1, and total integral 1"* is correct though does not add to what you said earlier (any pdf should integrate to $1$).

Comment: By symmetry/exchangeability, each segment has the same distribution, though they are not independent.  So you may as well consider the distribution of the segment between your first cut and the next cut clockwise round the loop.  You can work this out for finite $n$ and then in the limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us start by considering a fixed finite $N$. By symmetry, we only need to consider the segment clockwise from the first cut. That segment's length is determined by the minimum of the clockwise distances from the first cut to the $k$'th cut for $k>1$. The $k$'th cut will have clockwise distance $<x$ from the first cut with probability $\frac{x}{N}$, so the distribution of the minimum has a CDF of:

$$C_N(x) = 1 - \left(1-\frac{x}{N}\right)^{N-1}$$

Differentiating gives us a PDF of:

$$P_N(x) = \frac{N-1}{N}\left(1-\frac{x}{N}\right)^{N-2}$$

The distribution as $N\rightarrow \infty$ is given by:

$$
\begin{align}
P(x) &= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}P_N(x) \\
&= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{N-1}{N}\left(1-\frac{x}{N}\right)^{N-2} \\
&= \left(\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{N-1}{N}\left(1-\frac{x}{N}\right)^{-2}\right)\left(\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{N}\right)^{N}\right) \\
&= \left(1\right)\left(e^{-x}\right) \\
&= e^{-x}
\end{align}
$$
Here, we made use of the fact that the limit of a product is the product of the limits (provided the limits exist), and the fact that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+x/n)^n = e^x$.

It is easy to check that this function $P(x)=e^{-x}$ has center of mass at 1 and total integral 1. Its name is the exponential function.

Comment: How did you get from the second to last line to the last line?  ie How did you calculate that that $P(x)$ limit equation in terms of $N$ and $x$ is $e^{-x}$ ?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos I added a couple more steps and described their justification. Hope that helps.