# Simplification of limit to $e^{-x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

In the working of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4490602/22933) to a different problem, this simplification was presented:

$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{N-1}{N}\left(1-\frac{x}{N}\right)^{N-2} 
= e^{-x}
\end{align}
$$

I don't understand how this works?  How can you deduce $e^{-x}$ from this limit equation?

Comment: What is the limit of $\frac {N-1}N$ and the limit of $(1-\frac x N)^{-2}$?

Comment: Perhaps worth noting here that the acting principle is that For $a_n \to a$, $b_n \to b$, $a_n b_n \to ab$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\displaystyle \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{N-1}{N}\left(1-\frac xN\right)^{N-2}$$$$= \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{N-1}{N}\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1-\frac xN\right)^{N-2} = \lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1-\frac xN\right)^{N-2}$$$$=  \lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1-\frac xN\right)^{N}  \lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1-\frac xN\right)^{-2}=  \lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1-\frac xN\right)^{N}=e^{-x}. $$

This uses $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{N-1}{N}=1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac xN\right)^2}=1.$

Answer (score 1):

Since OP asked “how can we deduce $e^{-x}$”, I think the limit $\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1-\frac xN\right)^{N-2}$ will be more essential in the answer.

We compute $\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1-\frac xN\right)^{N-2}$ first. There is a trick: **taking logarithm**. For fixed $x$, we have $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac xN=0$; using $\log(1+t)\sim t$ as $t\to0$, we get
$$(N-2)\log\left(1-\frac xN\right)\sim (N-2)\cdot\left(-\frac x N\right),\qquad \text{as }\ \ \ N\to\infty;$$
since $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{N-2}N=1$, we have
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}(N-2)\log\left(1-\frac xN\right)=-x.$$
Now using the continuity of $t\mapsto e^t$,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1-\frac xN\right)^{N-2}&=\lim_{N\to \infty} e^{(N-2)\log\left(1-\frac xN\right)}\\
&=\exp\left(\lim_{N\to \infty}(N-2)\log\left(1-\frac xN\right)\right)\\
&=e^{-x}.
\end{align*}
Finally,
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{N-1}{N}\left(1-\frac xN\right)^{N-2}=\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{N-1}{N}\cdot\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1-\frac xN\right)^{N-2}=1\cdot e^{-x}=e^{-x}.$$

*Remark.* Taking logarithm is an approach often simplifying things surprisingly. See [my another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4490969/624428) for another example.